# DataTables warning: table id=TableTratamientosPanel - Ajax error

Tags: php

en mi xampp funciona bien pero cuando lo subo a un hosting me da este error de ajax, DataTables warning: table id=TableTratamientosPanel - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

como puedo resolver esto esta en codegniter